# Calculating the Depth of Asynchronous FIF0

Tags: digital-logic, fifo, questasim

Let us say  module A wants to send data to module B

**Writing Parameter of Module A:**
Width of Variable: 32-bit (the variable where data is written)

Frequency        : 20 MHz

**Reading Parameter of Module B:**

Frequency        : 20 MHz/ 16-bit Divisor

**Latency:** The data is written by module A after 1, 5 or 10 ms.
While the data is read by module B when the counter of module B reaches a 32-bit period value.

How to calculate the size of FIFO that is inserted between them?

Comment: Your description is difficult to understand. Are you saying that A writes at a rate that can vary from 100 to 1000 words per second, and that B reads at a rate of 20 MHz / 2^16 = 305 words per second? If so, the depth of the FIFO would depend on how "bursty" the data from A is -- i.e., for how long can it output more than 300 words/sec at a time?